# Hats popup isn't scrollable in the Samsung Internet browser

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022

On my mobile phone, I can open the hats' popup from my activity page, but one I do so, I cannot scroll it. Or rather, no matter how much I scroll, the screen doesn't move, and I'm left with the same top eight hats or so:

[image: no scrolling]

[image: some scrolling]

[image: lots of scrolling]

System details:

- Phone model: Samsung Galaxy 21 FE
- Android Version: 13
- Browser: Samsung Internet 19.0.3.12 (the latest version at the time this post was written)

Comment: I don't think that's a supported browser. You can download e.g. Chrome browser for your phone and use it if you want to enjoy the full features of SE. Edit: just checked, Stack Exchange supports only Chrome for android, and Safari for iOS, your browser is simply not supported so it's expected to break on some features.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars this occurs on Chrome too. You end up scrolling the actual page, not the pop-up.

Comment: @Luuklag oh, so better edit the original report.

Comment: Yeah I commented there too, @Sha.